How to preview created template as modal in GrapesJS
I created a template builder using GrapesJS and it works good.
I want to add a custom preview button, so users can see the result as modal by clicking the button.
I've been trying to find right solution in few days, but couldn't...
Please help me!
Here is my code:
const blocks = [
    {
        id: 'one-column',
        label: `1 Column`,
        category: 'Add Layout',
        attributes: { class: 'gjs-block-section' },
        content: `
            <div style="flex: 1; padding: 10px;">
                <h1>Column 1</h1>
            </div>
        `,
    },
    {
        id: 'two-column',
        label: `2 Column`,
        category: 'Add Layout',
        attributes: { class: 'gjs-block-section' },
        content: `
            <div style="display: flex; width: 100%">
                <div style="flex: 1; padding: 10px;">
                    <h1>Column 1</h1>
                </div>
                <div style="flex: 1; padding: 10px;">
                    <h1>Column 2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
    },
    { ... },
    {
        id: 'image',
        label: 'Image',
        category: 'Add Content',
        media: svgImage,
        activate: true,
        content: { type: 'image' }
    },
];

const editor = grapesjs.init({
    container: '.root',
    fromElement: true,
    height: '500px',
    width: '565px',
    storageManager: false,
    panels: {
        defaults: [{ ... }],
    },
    blockManager: {
        appendTo: '#blocks',
        blocks
    },
    selectorManager: { ... },
    styleManager: { ... }
});

Preview button
<div class="action-right">
    <a id="preview-btn">Preview</a>
</div>

Preview Modal
<div class="modal modal-lg" id="previewModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Template Preview</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="previewer"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Modal show operation
$('.preview-btn').click(function() {
    // let components = editor.getComponents();
    // let style = editor.getStyle()
    // let templateData = {
    //     components: components,
    //     style: style
    // };

    // --- here ---

    // $('#previewer').html('...');
    $('#previewModal').modal('show');
})


I have the same question
